# C preprocessor - define macro differently depending on another macro

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I have a debugging setup where you set various debug flags in the makefile, and then in each source file we have:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_FLAG
#    define DEBUGGING(...) Something(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DEBUGGING(...) do {} while(0)
#endif
```

I would like to make this be more concise by having the source file say something like:

```
#define DEBUGGING(...) DEBUG_HELP( DEBUG_FLAG, Something(__VA_ARGS__) )
```

where `DEBUG_HELP` is defined in a header, with the same end result, i.e. using the `DEBUGGING` macro will cause `Something` to be called, only if `DEBUG_FLAG` was defined as non-zero.  If `DEBUG_FLAG` was not defined at all then the code should still compile, just not call `Something`.

Is this possible at all?

My attempts so far, I have not been able to figure out a way to not get a compilation error in the case where `DEBUG_FLAG` was not defined at all.

Comment: Is there a restriction on how or where `DEBUG_HELP` is defined? Can it be wrapped in `#ifdef DEBUG_FLAG` condition?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here but why can't you simply do `#if DEBUG_FLAG 
#define DEBUGGING(...) Something(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if preprocessor symbol is defined inside macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099745/test-if-preprocessor-symbol-is-defined-inside-macro)

Answer (score 1):

Stealing from Nominal Animal's answer to a similar question, [Test if preprocessor symbol is defined inside macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099745/test-if-preprocessor-symbol-is-defined-inside-macro), the following should work. If `foo.c` is:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

#define DEBUG_HELP(flag, action)                      \
    do {                                              \
        if (strcmp(STRINGIFY(flag), #flag)) &&        \
            strcmp(STRINGIFY(flag), "0")) {           \
            action;                                   \
        }                                             \
    } while (0)

#define DEBUGGING(...) DEBUG_HELP(DEBUG_FLAG, printf(__VA_ARGS__))

DEBUGGING("%d\n", 42);
```

then:

```
$ gcc -E -P foo.c               
do { if (strcmp("DEBUG_FLAG", "DEBUG_FLAG")) && strcmp("DEBUG_FLAG", "0")) { printf("%d\n", 42); } } while (0);
$ gcc -E -P foo.c -DDEBUG_FLAG=0
do { if (strcmp("0", "DEBUG_FLAG")) && strcmp("0", "0")) { printf("%d\n", 42); } } while (0);
$ gcc -E -P foo.c -DDEBUG_FLAG  
do { if (strcmp("1", "DEBUG_FLAG")) && strcmp("1", "0")) { printf("%d\n", 42); } } while (0);
$ gcc -E -P foo.c -DDEBUG_FLAG=bar
do { if (strcmp("bar", "DEBUG_FLAG")) && strcmp("bar", "0")) { printf("%d\n", 42); } } while (0);
```

So with `DEBUG_FLAG` undefined or set to `0`, the `if` condition will be false. And if `DEBUG_FLAG` is anything else, with one exception, the condition will be true. The one exception is when you have:

```
#define DEBUG_FLAG DEBUG_FLAG
```

The `strcmp` should all be evaluated at compile-time with gcc, Clang, and MSVC, although I cannot find any guarantee. As a test, see the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    if (strcmp("foo", "foo"))
        return 888;
    if (&"foo" != &"foo") // '&' for Clang
        return 999;
    return 777;
}
```

compiled here at https://godbolt.org/g/2kVShr.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the condition in separate header file.

*debug_help.h*

```
#ifdef DEBUG_FLAG
    #define DEBUG_HELP(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
    #define DEBUG_HELP(...) do {} while(0)
#endif
```

*some_source_module.c*

```
#include "debug_help.h"
#define DEBUGGING(...) DEBUG_HELP(puts(__VA_ARGS__))

DEBUGGING("test"); // expands to puts("test"); when DEBUG_FLAG is defined
```

You could omit the `#include "debug_help.h"` if you can have compiler auto-include it for each compilation unit.