# Do efficiency cores support the same instructions as performance cores?

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, x86

When writing a program that requires high computational performance, it is often required that multiple threads, SIMD vectorization, or other extensions are required. One can query the CPU using CPUID to find out what instruction set it supports. However, since the programmer has no control over which cores are actually executing the different threads, it could be a problem if different cores support different instruction sets.

If one queries the CPU at the start of the program, is it safe to assume all threads will support the same instruction set? If not, then does this break programs that assume they do all support the same instructions or are the CPUs clever enough to realize they shouldn't use those cores?

Does one need to query CPUID on each thread separately?

Is there any way a program can avoid running on E-cores?

If the instruction sets are the same, then where is the 'Efficiency'? Is it with less cache, lower clock speed, or something else?

This question is posed out of curiosity, but the answers may affect how I write programs in the future. I would appreciate any informed comments on these questions but please don't just share your thoughts and opinions on how you think it works if you don't know with high confidence. Thanks.

I have only tried to find information on the internet, but found nothing of sufficiently low level to answer these questions adequately.

Comment: `then where is the 'Efficiency'` power efficiency.

Comment: This is why AVX512 was disabled in 12th and 13th gen. But get ready for that to change.

Comment: Still no heterogenous x86 in terms of ISA extensions, only some tiny differences in some CPUID leafs.  (And of course performance, like most 256-bit vector instructions decoding to 2 uops, or more for lane-crossing shuffles.  As well as other performance diffs.)  I haven't checked if the PMU supports the same events; that could be another difference between cores that affects programs like Linux `perf` itself, or the kernel code it talks to.

Comment: See also [What are performance and efficiency cores in Intel's 12th Generation Alder lake CPU Line?](https://superuser.com/a/1677779) for some details on the point of efficiency cores.  Ancestor of Silvermont, not Sandybridge, and their SIMD ALUs are only 128-bit wide.  But still fairly capable of running AVX code somewhat quickly, so good for throughput in video encoding for example.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks for the links to the articles. It appears then, that the answer is no, cores can support different instruction sets. How then, is a programmer supposed to know what extensions can safely be used? This looks like a badly thought out mess to me.

Comment: They *could* in a hypothetical design, but like I and harold said, they *don't* in Intel's current design. And as yet there's no OS support for letting programs handle heterogeneous  ISA extensions support on x86.  Presumably that's something people are thinking about, hopefully as a way to allow heterogeneity like 512-bit vector instructions on the P-cores, but not the E-cores of future CPUs.  (Hopefully still 256-bit AVX-512VL instructions on the E cores, especially if they support masked loads and stores efficiently; stuff like glibc memcpy will use if available.)

Comment: Does this mean that I can trust CPUID to tell me which extensions I can safely use in any single or multi-threaded program?

Comment: @SimonGoater that is safe now and should remain safe (otherwise it would break existing software), but if some mechanism is introduced to move threads onto P-cores "as necessary" then code that isn't careful will find itself unable to use the E-cores.

Answer (score 2):

> Do efficiency cores support the same instructions as performance cores?

Yes (for Intel's Alder lake, but also for big.LITTLE ARM).

For Alder Lake; operating systems were "deemed unable" to handle heterogeneous CPUs; so Intel nerfed existing support for extensions that already existed in performance cores (primarily AVX-512) to match the features present in the efficiency cores.

Sadly, supporting heterogeneous CPU isn't actually hard in some cases (e.g. hypervisors that don't give all CPUs to a single guest) and is solvable in the general case; and failing to provide a way to re-enable disabled extensions (if an OS supports heterogeneous CPUs) prevents an OS from trying to support heterogeneous CPUs in future; essentially turning a temporary solution into a permanent problem.

> Does one need to query CPUID on each thread separately?

Not for the purpose of determining feature availability. If you have highly optimized code (e.g. code tuned differently for different CPU types) you might still want to (even though it's not a strict need); but will also need to pin the thread to a specific CPU or group of CPUs.

> Is there any way a program can avoid running on E-cores?

Potentially, via. CPU affinity. Typically it just makes things worse though (better to run on an E core than to not run at all because P cores are already busy).

> If the instruction sets are the same, then where is the 'Efficiency'? Is it with less cache, lower clock speed, or something else?

Lower clock, shorter pipeline, less aggressive speculative execution, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm interested to see what other comments come in on this subject. Do you know if disabling an extension such as AVX512 automatically affects the return values from CPUID or could it be that CPUID would still return values suggesting that the extension is available?

Comment: Previous generations of *mont cores didn't support AVX2, so at least they met in the middle and added support for that in the Gracemont E-cores.

Comment: @SimonGoater: CPUID reports no AVX-512F on CPUs that don't support AVX-512, of course. Anything else would be totally broken and lead to programs crashing. So it's just like when they disable it on a Pentium or Celeron model of Ice Lake or whatever.  Or on client Skylake cores, which have all the execution units and register files, just not enabled.

Comment: @SimonGoater: Always remember: if a new CPU made existing programs crash, that would be a big reason for people to *not* buy it.  Backwards compatibility is a huge deal for x86; it's been the driving force behind the evolution of the ISA since 8086, e.g. the strong memory model matches 486/Pentium. (Unfortunately including the jump to x86-64 which had no true technical need to keep all the same inconveniences of every instruction and the machine-code format, except for sharing decoder transistors in AMD CPUs before they knew whether it would catch on or be dead weight for them.)

Comment: I guess if you wanted a heterogeneous CPU architecture, you could make the 'E' cores recognize the obscure instructions supported by the 'P' cores, halt execution, and tell the OS to switch it to 'P' core only. Then CPUID could show just 'P' core ISA extensions and programmers wouldn't need to worry about it crashing from trying to execute instructions valid on 'P' cores but not on 'E' cores. As a programmer, I need to be able to trust that the results from CPUID that tell me what extensions I can use, will not crash the program. Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: @SimonGoater: Having E cores ask the OS to migrate to P cores on use of an insn they don't support would result in everything running on P cores only.  Stuff like glibc `memcpy` or `memcmp` use AVX-512 masked loads/stores to handle odd lengths (with 256-bit vectors) if AVX-512 is available.