# Is there a way to write a C/C++ function-like macro that tests if an object-like macro is defined and generates code uses it?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I can find other questions on the site about using `#if` and `#ifdef` inside macros, and ways to get around the restriction to achieve various things, but none of them or their answers seem to match my use-case, which seems like an obvious one to me:

```cpp
// the system flags are defined as object-like macros in this header...
#include <sys/stat.h>

// naive attempt at function-like macro that of course cannot work
#define MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(flag)                \
  #if defined(flag).                           \
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, #flag), \
                Napi::Number::New(env, flag)); \
  #endif


Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(UF_NODUMP)
    MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(UF_IMMUTABLE)
    MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(UF_APPEND)

    return exports;
}
```

For instance, [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099745) seems similar and a workaround is provided, but I couldn't adapt that set of macros to my case, or if it is adaptable I'm not understanding something there. In any case it doesn't use the macro's parameter in the generated code.

I did find that there were some tricks around to do what some of the other questions wanted but I couldn't find a way to adapt any of them to this case. But they are quite tricky. So is there some trick or is it simply impossible?

Comment: Until C++ has reflection, which might come eventually, this is not practical without explicitly defining your own `#define` tags.

Comment: @hippietrail A _"preprocessor symbol"_ is called a macro.

Answer (score 2):

What you end up needing to do is define a macro for every symbol of interest that expands based on whether the symbol is defined:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef UF_NODUMP
#define IFDEF_UF_NODUMP(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IFDEF_UF_NODUMP(...)
#endif
#ifdef UF_IMMUTABLE
#define IFDEF_UF_IMMUTABLE(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IFDEF_UF_IMMUTABLE(...)
#endif
#ifdef UF_APPEND
#define IFDEF_UF_APPEND(...)  __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IFDEF_UF_APPEND(...)
#endif

#define MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(flag)                    \
    IFDEF_ ## flag(                                \
        exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, #flag), \
                    Napi::Number::New(env, flag)); \
    )

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(UF_NODUMP)
    MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(UF_IMMUTABLE)
    MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG(UF_APPEND)

    return exports;
}
```

This is somewhat painful and repetitive, but you can put all the repeated stuff in its own header file somewhere that you don't need to refer to much.  Depending on what you are are trying to do, you might find it useful to define `IFNDEF_` macros for each symbol as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach, for interest (with a caveat--see bolded list entry).  This doesn't use your `MAYBE_EXPORT_FLAG` skeleton, but:

- It's a bit more generic (based on pattern matching)
- Usage is less verbose than giant chains of conditional directives (detects undefined flags using pattern matching)
- Works with identifier-like flags (anything right-pasteable to an identifier; includes positive decimals, octals, hex numbers)
- Works with parenthetical flags
- **WILL NOT WORK** for (non-parenthetical) "negative" flags (e.g., if your system defines a flag as `#define FLAG -1`)

### Base macros

```
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_I(__VA_ARGS__,,)
#define SECOND_I(A,B,...) B
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
#define EAT(...)
#define IF_NMATCHES_USEABLE(P_, F_, M_) M_
#define IF_NMATCHES_P(...) , IF_NMATCHES_USEABLE
#define IF_NMATCHES_CALL(P_,F_,M_) \
    SECOND(IF_NMATCHES_P F_, IF_NMATCHES_D2)(P_, F_, M_)
#define IF_NMATCHES_D2(P_,F_,M_) \
    SECOND(GLUE(P_, F_), IF_NMATCHES_USEABLE)(P_, F_, M_)
#define MATCHED_PATTERN(P_, F_, M_) EAT
```

### Usage

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
// Match macros (prefix plus flag)
#define STAT_FLAG_UF_NODUMP    ,MATCHED_PATTERN
#define STAT_FLAG_UF_IMMUTABLE ,MATCHED_PATTERN
#define STAT_FLAG_UF_APPEND    ,MATCHED_PATTERN
// Apply 
#define EXPORT_FLAG(FLAG_) \
   exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, #FLAG_), \
               Napi::Number::New(env, FLAG_));
Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    IF_NMATCHES_CALL(STAT_FLAG_,UF_NODUMP,EXPORT_FLAG)(UF_NODUMP)
    IF_NMATCHES_CALL(STAT_FLAG_,UF_IMMUTABLE,EXPORT_FLAG)(UF_IMMUTABLE)
    IF_NMATCHES_CALL(STAT_FLAG_,UF_APPEND,EXPORT_FLAG)(UF_APPEND)

    return exports;
}
```

Semantically, `IF_NMATCHES_CALL` takes as arguments a prefix, a flag, and the name of a function-like macro.  It will expand to `EAT` if the pattern matches, or your function-like macro's name if it doesn't.  Then you add call arguments; `EAT` is a variadic macro that swallows those arguments and expands to nothing... your macro does what you want.

A pattern is matched if there is a "pattern-match" macro; the pattern match macro has a name equivalent to the prefix and the flag you're checking, and a replacement list of `,MATCHED_PATTERN` (comma is significant, see below).

### Mechanism

The core here uses C preprocessor pattern matching via an indirect `SECOND` macro.  By default this macro expands to its second argument; when used as a pattern matcher, you would arrange the first argument to produce a token to be matched; for match cases you define a macro with that name and put a comma in that macro's replacement list, which shifts in a non-default macro.

The top level macro first applies a pattern matcher on parenthesized flag replacement lists; in such cases, `IF_NMATCHES_P` will expand, shifting `IF_NMATCHES_USEABLE`.  If the flag doesn't expand to a parenthesized list, the second level `IF_NMATCHES_D2` is called.  This call matches on the prefix/suffix combination (the `GLUE` here is what would fail if your system defined the flag as a negative literal, as e.g. `-1` is not right-pasteable); if your flag is not defined, the result of this would be your match macro, which will shift in `MATCHED_PATTERN` resulting in the `EAT`.  If your flag is defined, the argument is ignored by the `SECOND` macro resulting in `IF_NMATCHES_USEABLE`.  `IF_NMATCHES_USEABLE` is what expands to `M_`.

### Demo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d151d475f2736141