# C preprocessor macro that emits a struct if some other macro is defined?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to define a Cpp macro, say ENO_DECL(eno, func) that expands as follows

```
#define ENO_DECL(eno, func) { eno, #eno, func }
```

so I can write e.g., `ENO_DECL(ENOMEM, resource_error)`  That works fine of course.  Some platform may not define all errors though, so we'd need something like this:

```
#ifdef EXYZ
ENO_DECL(EXYZ, type_error)
#endif
```

This is of course not so elegant.   I'd like to get rid of the `#ifdef` and have the `ENO_DECL()` expanded to nothing if `EXYZ` is not defined.  I've read a couple of interesting posts and blogs with really nice cpp tricks, but this one doesn't seem to be covered.  I have the impression this can be done though (portable).   Is that right?  ... and how?

Comment: I remember a really nice tutorial for a preprocessor-time `if` statement you can make to put inside macros, see http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic Perhaps you could use this? Note that it won't work well as a replacement for `ifdef`, since it will return true if it finds a macro that isn't defined, only maybe as a very limited `if` that sees if a macro evaluates to true or false. So this probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897544/is-there-a-way-to-write-a-c-c-function-like-macro-that-tests-if-an-object-like)?

Comment: @HWalters I think you are right.   Unfortunately it IMO not really better than just using #ifdef everywhere the straightforward way unless you need to macro many times (which I do not).  @mediocrevegetable1 `ifdef` is what I need :(

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to get rid of the #ifdef

That is not possible. You could use some code generation tool or other preprocessing tools. For example, using `m4`:

```
#include <errno.h>

/** m4 code here
define(`ENO', `#ifdef $1
    ENO_DECL($1, $2),
#endif')
*/
#define ENO(x) /* just so that IDE does not complain */
#define ENO_DECL(eno, func) { eno, #eno, func }

typedef struct {
  int eno;
  const char* str;
  void (*handler)(void);
} eno_t;
const eno_t eno [] = {
    ENO(ENOMEM, abc)
    ENO(E_DOES_NOT_EXISTS, def)
};
```

You can inspect such code with for example `m4 file.c.m4 | gcc -E -xc -` and the preprocessor output is:

```
const eno_t eno [] = {

 { 
# 16 "<stdin>" 3 4
12
# 16 "<stdin>"
, "ENOMEM", abc },




};
```

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you would get rid of all these macros to begin with. These aren't "nice tricks", they are last resorts, when you are maintaining some badly written code and has to patch everything together with weird function-like macros and other desperate measures.

Anyway, it would appear that the solution you are looking for is "X macros". How they work are explained on Wikipedia etc. Basically it's an "industry de facto"  standardized way to centralize all code repetition to a single place in the code base. Useful for code maintenance but should be avoided when developing new code. An example:

```c
#define ENO_LIST(X)         \
  X(ENOMEM, resource_error) \
  X(ENOFOO, foo_error)      \
  ...

typedef struct
{
  int eno;
  const char* str;
  void (*handler)(void);
} eno_t;

const eno_t eno [ENO_N] = 
{
  #define X(n, func) {n, #n, func},
    ENO_LIST(X)
  #undef X
};
```

This struct list will then expand to:

```c
const eno_t eno [ENO_N] = 
{
  {ENOMEM, "ENOMEM", resource_error},
  {ENOFOO, "ENOFOO", resource_error},
  ...
};
```

If `ENOMEM` is part of an `enum` with indices 0 to N, you could increase data integrity a bit further like this:

```
typedef enum
{
  ENOMEM,
  ENOFOO,
  ...
  ENO_N
} enom;

...

#define X(n, func) [n] = {n, #n, func},  // [n] is a designated initializer

...

_Static_assert(sizeof eno / sizeof *eno == ENO_N, "Enum and struct don't match");
```